# When an ability lets you reduce a creature's speed to 0, does it include fly/swim/climb speed?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

There are some abilities like **Sentinel** which let you reduce a creature's speed to 0.

If a creature with any kind of other speed, like climbing-, flying- or swimming speed can it use these to move, or are **all** speeds reduced to 0?

For example, a Dragon, which is moving out of melee range gets hit by someone's opportunity attack and has its speed reduced to 0. Can it still fly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### All speeds will be reduced to 0.

Specifically you cannot fly when your speed is 0:

PHB p. 191

> #### Flying Movement
>
> If a flying creature is knocked prone, **has its speed reduced to 0**,
> or is otherwise deprived of the ability to move, the creature falls,
> unless it has the ability to hover or it is being held aloft by magic,
> such as by the fly spell.

As for other miscellaneous types of movement, they also depend on speed:

PHB p. 182

> **Special Types of Movement**
>
> Movement through dangerous dungeons or wilderness areas often involves more than simply walking. Adventurers might have to climb, crawl, swim, or jump to get where they need to go.
>
> **Climbing, Swimming, and Crawling**
>
> While climbing or swimming, **each foot of movement costs 1 extra foot (2 extra feet in difficult terrain), unless a creature has a climbing or swimming speed**. At the GM’s option, climbing a slippery vertical surface or one with few handholds requires a successful Strength (Athletics) check. Similarly, gaining any distance in rough water might require a successful Strength (Athletics) check.

Since these depend on movement, if you can't move because your speed is 0 you cannot preform them.

---

In general, all of your speeds are connected and when you use part of your speed for one type of movement, it subtracts it from all. The PHB has a good example of this:

PHB p. 190

> #### Using Different Speeds
>
> If you have more than one speed, such as your
> walking speed and a flying speed, you can switch back and forth
> between your speeds during your move. Whenever you switch, subtract
> the distance you've already moved from the new speed. The result
> determines how much farther you can move. If the result is 0 or less,
> you can’t use the new speed during the current move.
>
> For example, if
> you have a speed of 30 and a flying speed of 60 because a wizard cast
> the fly spell on you, you could fly 20 feet, then walk 10 feet, and
> then leap into the air to fly 30 feet more.

Comment: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/770683371735232512 - this might be relevant to add to your answer.